# jinja2 dynamic html table from python in flask

Tags: html, flask, dynamic, jinja2

I would like create dynamic table with value from 2 sql query in postgresql.
From first query I would like to create first 6 row and seven row should be link to files.

First queries I create value2 from which I create table.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="xxx" width="100%" data-name="mytable">
 
 
        <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th onclick="sortTable(0, 'xxx')">aaa</th> 
            <th onclick="sortTable(1, 'xxx')">bbb</th> 
            <th onclick="sortTable(2, 'xxx')">ccc</th> 
            <th onclick="sortTable(3, 'xxx')">ddd</th> 
            <th onclick="sortTable(4, 'xxx')">eee</th> 
            <th onclick="sortTable(5, 'xxx')">fff</th> 
        </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
            {% for row in value2%}  
                <tr> 
                    <td>{{row[0]}}</td> 
                    <td>{{row[1]}}</td> 
                    <td>{{row[2]}}</td> 
                    <td>{{row[3]}}</td> 
                    <td>{{row[4]}}</td> 
                    <td>{{row[5]}}</td> 
                </tr> 
            {% endfor %} 
        </tbody> 
</table>
```

From second query I get value11 as link to files and I would like to set link to this files as last column in tables

```
{% for plik in value11 %}      
       <td>
                    <form action="{{ url_for('static', filename=plik|string +'.xml') }}">
                        <input type="submit" value="pokaz plik" />
                    </form>
                </td> 
         {% endfor %}
```

Can anyone help how create this table?
I try use this code but it's wrong idea ;/

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="czyodramke" width="100%" data-name="mytable">
 
 
        <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th onclick="sortTable(0, 'xxx')">aaa</th> 
            <th onclick="sortTable(1, 'xxx')">bbb</th> 
            <th onclick="sortTable(2, 'xxx')">ccc</th> 
            <th onclick="sortTable(3, 'xxx')">ddd</th> 
            <th onclick="sortTable(4, 'xxx')">eee</th> 
            <th onclick="sortTable(5, 'xxx')">fff</th> 
        </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
            {% for row in value2%}  
            {% for plik in value11 %}
                <tr> 
                    <td>{{row[0]}}</td> 
                    <td>{{row[1]}}</td> 
                    <td>{{row[2]}}</td> 
                    <td>{{row[3]}}</td> 
                    <td>{{row[4]}}</td> 
                    <td>{{row[5]}}</td> 
 
                 <td>
                        <form action="{{ url_for('static', filename=plik|string +'.xml') }}">
                            <input type="submit" value="pokaz plikl" />
                        </form>
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
            {% endfor %} 
             {% endfor %}
        </tbody> 
</table>
```

This is how I get value2 and value11

```
cursor.execute (slq_query)
data2 = cursor.fetchall()   
data11 = cursor.fetchall()
data11len = (len(data11))
lst = list(range(data11len))
print (lst)
for i in range (len(data11)):
naszplik = ''.join(data11[i])
with open(f"project/static/{i}.xml", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
f.write(naszplik)
return render_template('wyniki.html', value2=data2, value11=lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use variables from the server in Jinja, you have to surround them in double braces: `{{ variable }}`. Not doing this will cause Jinja and therefore Flask to ignore your variable. I think you may be missing some braces in a few cases. For example, you do this:

```html
{% for plik in value11 %}      
       <td>
                    <form action="{{ url_for('static', filename=plik|string +'.xml') }}">
                        <input type="submit" value="pokaz plik" />
                    </form>
                </td> 
         {% endfor %}
```

You use `plik` a couple of times, but it's just a string of the word "plik", not the variable assigned to the current iteration of `value11`. It's very easy to solve, simply wrap in `{{ }}` and see if that does the trick

Answer (score 0):

My problem isn't second query only that I would like create table form 2 variables like this table:

```
|aaa |bbb   |ccc  |ddd  |eee  |plik  |
|aaa1 |bbb1 |ccc1 |ddd1 |eee1 |plik1 |
|aaa2 |bbb2 |ccc2 |ddd2 |eee2 |plik2 |
```

Now I have 2 different tables:
first table

```
|aaa  |bbb   |ccc  |ddd  |eee  |
|aaa1 |bbb1 |ccc1 |ddd1 |eee1 |
|aaa2 |bbb2 |ccc2 |ddd2 |eee2 |
```

second table

```
|plik  |
|plik1 |
|plik2 |
```